# How Can I run a method when window.load completes BUT also used on re-render in React?

Tags: reactjs

I need to call a method when window has been loaded, but when I navigate through pages and then I return to the page that contains `myComponent`, the `doSomething()` method is not being executed because `windowLoaded` only happens once.

So, I added a global variable to keep the `windowloaded` value as a `true` and enter to `doSomething()` method again, and this solution works... **BUT** is this the best way to achieve this?

**myComponent**

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

let windowHasLoaded = false

const myComponent = ({}) => {

  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false)

  const handleWindowLoaded = () => {
    windowHasLoaded = true
    setIsReady(true)
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {

    if (windowLoaded) {
      doSomething()
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', handleWindowLoaded)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('load', handleWindowLoaded)
    };

  }, [isReady]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>Test</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default myComponent;
```

Comment: Are you using iframes? I don't see why you would ever need to listen for that event on the current page inside React (Since React wouldn't be running until the page has finished loading)

Comment: yes! iframes, or third party scripts that takes time to be ready.